# Ghostscript on Unix generating huge files

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdfa

I use Ghostscript 9.14, the [last one](http://83.133.184.251/hpux.connect/hppd/hpux/PostScript/ghostscript-9.14.0/index.html) compiled for HP-Unix.

I need to create PDF/A-1b files from existing pdf files from different sources.
It is preferred that this happens on a HP-Unix server because that is the server that puts them in a DMS.

The command:

```
gs -q -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE \
-dCCFONTDEBUG -dCFFDEBUG -dCMAPDEBUG -dDOCIEDEBUG -dEPSDEBUG \
-dFAPIDEBUG -dINITDEBUG -dPDFDEBUG -dPDFOPTDEBUG -dPDFWRDEBUG \
-dSETPDDEBUG -dSTRESDEBUG -dTTFDEBUG -dVGIFDEBUG -dVJPGDEBUG \
-dColorConversionStrategy=/sRGB -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=2 \
-sOutputFile=debug_0901ece380001a00.pdf /usr/../PDFA_def.ps \
/0901ece380001a00.pdf
```

The source pdf is filled with just non-OCRed images.

I have this working on a newer version on a Windows server (Ghostscript 9.19) without problems and with the same command but can't seem to get it working on HP-Unix.
On the Windows server there is a MS Office installed.

The HP-Unix command generates 9mb file for a 300kb source file and it takes ages to generate.
Ghostscript seems single threaded but 9 mins for 35 pages is a bit much.
When I check through Preflight in Acrobat Pro 9 Extended, the 9mb file is truly PDF-A 1b.

Do I need to install a kind of Office software on Unix to get this working?
Or an image editing tool?

Also, how do I check the debug lines? They aren't in a readable format and I can't find any info on that.
Maybe it is something that only can be checked by the Ghostscript developers?

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the input file contains transparency. PDF/A-1 does not support transparency, and so when creating PDF/A-1 files any page which does contain transparency is rendered to an image, and then that image is embedded in the output.

Clearly this will take time (rendering a page at 720 dpi, full colour, and transparency processing is slow) and will result in a large file. However, its the only way to preserve the appearance of the input file and still create a PDF/A-1 file.

Of course, in the absence of an example input file to examine its not possible to be certain of this.

The DEBUG lines switches are useless except to Ghostscript developers, don't bother to set them. You would never set so many anyway, you'll be swamped with extraneous detail. I'm doubtful all the ones you have listed are even valid.

You say you have this 'working' with Ghostscript 9.19 on Windows, what do you mean by 'working' ? It seems to me that the 9.14 output 'works' as well.....

As far as I know we have never compiled a Ghostscript release for HP/UX, but the current version (9.22) is known to compile and run on HP/UX.

Finally Ghostscript does not rely on (and indeed cannot make use of) Microsoft Office. Nor does it rely on the operating system for anything except memory and file access.

Comment: When generating this file on a Windows 2012r2 server the source file (600kb) generates a destination file of 600kb. When this happens on GS 9.14 on HP-Unix, it generates a 9mb file. I'm wondering about the file size as I need to do this with a lot of files in a DMS. It seems on HP-Unix, it doesn't use image compression. How can I send you a file?

Comment: I can't test on a HP/UX server, so there's not a huge amount of point in sending me the file, other than to determine whether the file contains transparency or not. If you really want to you can send a file to ken at spamcop.net. You could try running 9.14 on Windows and see if you get the same effect. If you do, then you know that something changed in the 2 years between those versions, and you need to upgrade your HP/UX version. NB the current release is 9.22 so you are fairly well behind the times even on Windows.

Comment: You were right. Version 9.14 was the culprit. Thanks a bunch.